# RIP Harry Dean Stanton

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Noted character actor [**Harry Dean Stanton**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Dean_Stanton) has died at the age of 91.

In a career spanning more than 60 years, he starred in a number of hit science-fiction and fantasy films including Alien, The Green Mile, Repo Man, Twin Peaks: Fire Walk with Me, Escape from New York and The Avengers.

[image]
<sub><sup>Samuel Brett: Alien</sup></sub>

Comment: [Funny tweets ensued](https://twitter.com/MrMichaelSpicer/status/908820022876884993)